how to correct "unknown root shell" in shell in a box
I'm having problem of directory due to a typo in a command I wrote in my command
I made a typo while writing this command
chsh -s/usr/local/bin/bash/<username>
instead of using this chsh -s/usr/local/bin/bash <username>
because of that, when I want to use the su command I receive not a directory error and I didn't know that to do. chsh -s/usr/local/bin/bash in order to solve it my self, but it gave me this error: pwd_mkdb: warning, unknown root shell, and displayed chsh: user information updated. But the issue persisted.
Additional info: Os NAME=FreeBSD;VERSION="13.3-RELEASE-p4";VERSION_ID="13.3".

Welcome to unix.se . You should NOT change the root user default shell (if that's what you are trying to do). the root user is used for many things, especially during the startup of your OS, and you could end up with problems if some of those commands expected the "correct" shell (those that don't specify on their first line #!/which/shell/to/use).

@OlivierDulac have you ever run into that in practice? As far as I’m aware, the root user’s shell is never used as a fallback shell — the fallback is /bin/sh (for scenarios where a shell script is run without a shebang for example).

@stephen-kitt: One of the reasons (amongs more) is : when booting in single-user, the root sheel needs to not depend on any possibly-on-another-partition-that-slash files : see the (old but still interresting) [https://groups.google.com/g/comp.unix.shell/c/ATpmISWn2qg/m/tceZO3DUszoJ](comp.unix.shell FAQ, Q.17)

@OlivierDulac right, I know about that, but that only affects root’s ability to log in (and is definitely a valid reason to avoid changing the root user’s shell indiscriminately). What I’m interested in is this: when does the root user’s shell affect startup scripts?

@StephenKitt : I have to admit I don't remember exactly, but in my memory things could happen during /etc/rc.d (so, the old system) executions if some of those scripts didn't have the proper shebang.

Do not change root default password.
At the very least:

it could mess up your ability to boot in rescue mode (single-user), as in this mode only the "/" (root) partition would be available at first (ie, before you open a shell) and your new shell may not be launchable only with "/" available (for exemple if you have a separate /usr partition, chances are that those contains bits your new shell needs to be launched).
it also could change the way the shell behaves, so other possible users login as root may end up surprised by differences
I believe it could mess up the startup process, but that was possibly way back when (and when using /etc/rc* startup mechanisms)... it is probably no longer relevant

I'd advise: instead:

Create an alias in the user you use usually (I really hope you almost never log in as root, but with a low_rights_user.
In this user's ~/.bashrc, you could add an alias that helps you quickly start the relevant user & shell :

for exemple: in your ~regularuser/.bashrc file:
alias gR="sudo -u root bash -l"  # or /path/to/bash if needed.
# -l = lowercaseL, which tells bash to run as if a login shell
#  hence it will read more of the bashrc/etc files when starting


Edit /etc/passwdor /etc/master.passwd directly, there is a line for your user that also specifies the path to the shell.
